# Dropwizard/Jersey - Service domain from config file

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, dropwizard

Is there a way to inject into the @Path annotation a string from the yaml config file used to run the Dropwizard service?

I can't find anything on the [guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html).
Thanks

**Example:**

Config file:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 5555
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 5556
my-service-domain: /my-service
```

Resource:

```
@Path("#{my-config.my-service-domain}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class MyResource {
...
}
```

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34990765/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

For Dropwizard 0.8.0 and newer this is achieved from this configuration:

```
applicationContextPath: /
rootPath: /application
```

Where applicationContextPath is Jetty's Context path, and rootPath is Jersey's.