# Is there a way to append to end of @Path

Tags: java, rest, jersey

If we have the code below

```
@Path("/basepath")
  public class YourBaseResource {

  @Path("a/b")
  @GET
  public Responce method1(){
    return Response.ok("blah blah").build();
  }

  @Path("a/b/c")
  @GET
  public Response method2(){
    UriBuilder addressBuilder = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder();
    addressBuilder.path("a/b");
    return Response.seeOther(addressBuilder.build()).build();
  }

}
```

then the following two URLs will be available

```
 /basepath/a/b
 /basepath/a/b/c/
```

My question is that if I want to append /x to the end of all the urls so that the client is able to access them as

```
/basepath/a/b/x
/basepath/a/b/c/x
```

then apart from writing /x at the end of each @Path annotation for every @GET on every method, is there a way to specify it a) just once in the parent or b) bind /x to a variable somehow and then use it at the end of path for each @GET?

Answer (score 0):

Jersey builds a model of all the resources, including their paths. So if you wanted, you could rewrite the paths in the resource models, using a [`ModelProcessor`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html#d0e11416), as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990765/2587435)

Comment: I tried reading your post but could not figure out the answer.
I have edited the question a little bit if you could please see it again.